# How do I stack multiple columns into one?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[image: Example Data]

I am not experienced enough with VBA to accomplish this. How do I modify the below VBA to be able to do the following:

1. Put stacked columns in a new sheet.
2. Handle blanks (code below currently does this)

3.code executes on the range the user has currently selected. Ideally user can select non-contiguous columns.

```
Sub MoveAllDataToColumnA()
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, rngCopy As Range, rngEnd As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Do Until ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = ""
        Set rngCopy = ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        Set rngEnd = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        rngEnd.Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, 1).Value = rngCopy.Value
        rngCopy.EntireColumn.Delete
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I would use the Power Query Add-In for this, but it cant handle requirement #3.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Power Query. As in my other post this will also work.  I am not as worried about requirement #3 since Power Query, I found out, has an alternative way of accomplishing the same thing. If you submit your response as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this, although it cant handle requirement #3. From Excel 2016, Power Query is built in to the Data ribbon under "Get and Transform" section.

The Steps I would create in the Power Query would be:

Select Org and Length columns, then choose "Remove Columns".

Select Category column and choose "Unpivot columns / Unpivot other columns".

You can deliver the result into a new Excel Table.